# What are the side effects of taking Omega 3 with steroids during an MS attack?

Tags: multiple-sclerosis

Are there any bad effects from taking prednisolone tablets (solupred) with omega 3 in case of an MS attack? I googled and I found out that there are no interaction between them. I'm curious to know if mixing omega 3 and prednisolone has side effects, complications, or any other bad effects.

Comment: We can't guess at his reasoning, so you'll need to ask him.

Comment: @Carey Gregory Aren't there common or standard reasons that doctors follow? I googled and found out there are no interaction between Omega3 and steroids.  Maybe I'm missing something else other than the interaction thing.

Comment: I don't know. You could formulate a question about this that would be acceptable here, but this question asks us to explain your doctor's reasoning on a decision he made about **you**, and that crosses the line into personal medical advice.

Comment: @CareyGregory Done :)